# Extract Text from web page displayed in a TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I use delphi 7 and I would like to extract ONLY the text displayed in a webpage directly from a web page displayed in a TWebBrowser (no images....). Could it be done & how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the following...

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
 var
  Document: IHtmlDocument2;
begin
  edit1.text:=url;
  document := webbrowser1.document as IHtmlDocument2;
  memo2.lines.add(trim(document.body.innerhtml));  // to get html
  memo1.lines.add(trim(document.body.innertext));  // to get text
end;
```

Comment: Thank you PA : this is exactly what I need to do !
I would like to copy the text into a TRichedit : Is there any way to keep the formatting (bold, H1...) of the text?

Comment: you might need to remove all the <img> tags and display de html back to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If your wanting to load this into a TRichEdit, then I suggest looking at the [WPTools](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/wptools/index.htm) component which has the ability to load the data from an HTML stream, and export as RTF.  I use this component to handle my internal email editor (which it appears is what your after).